# Images lazy loading on Elementor's loop elements

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, elementor

Elementor's loop feature lazy loads images.  The bug affects FCP performance when using it above the fold, like in the project I'm working on, and using different attributes doesn't affect it.

The project is in late stages of optimization but I can't figure this one out.

[website audit by Google Page Speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgtu.png)

- Loop is a relatively new Elementor Pro feature;
- I use Lite Speed Cache plugin (LSC);
- LSC defers both images and iframes, and can prevent it using custom classes;
- LSC supports "data-no-lazy=1" attribute on HTML;
- I tried both data-no-lazy|1 and fetch-priority|high (Elementor syntax) in img, iframe and parent iframe. Also tried it both on the custom loop iframe on the page I put the loop on;
- Apparently all images have decoding="async" and loading="lazy" attributes by default when using LSC;
- The img attributes appears even when removing LSC optimization, so it seems to be added to the img tag itself;
- since the website is dynamic and exhibits posts contents based on specific tags I can't exclude the image file directly from lazy loading;
- I tried deactivating image lazy loading on LSC to keep it only for iframes but it doesn't affect visitors mode (optimized), which is what matters anyway;
- I tried deactivating lazy loading features on Elementor's experimental features but it didn't work, only lost performance.